# Check if a mysgl table exists with php

Tags: php, mysql

To start with: I know this question has been asked before, but I am looking for a working solution for over a week now and I can't find one. So please can anyone help me instead of just marking my question as a duplicate? Thanks already!!

So the question is this: I'm trying to check if a mysql table exists in my database (with php). Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? This is my code as far as I get:

```
<form id="newChat" method="post">
    Start a new chat: 
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php
function checkChat($me, $friend) {
    global $conn;
    $chatid = findChat($me, $friend);

    $sql  = 'SHOW TABLES FROM chatboxDB LIKE \'chat10\'';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);

    if ($result > 0) {
        echo '<script>alert("It works.");</script>';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $friend = checkInput($_POST["name"]);
    unset($_POST["name"]);
    checkChat($me, $friend);
}
?>
```

Some remarks:

- the mysqli_query() function works in other parts of my code
- the connection $conn to my database works
- the problem seems to be in `if ($result > 0)` --> this seems to be always true...

**Edit: This is now my code and it is working:**
(I found it could be done a lot more simple)

```
<?php
function checkChat($me, $friend) {
    global $conn, $dbname;
    $chatid = findChat($me, $friend); # the findChat() is a query to find the name of a chat by giving the 2 persons from that chat, if one of those 2 persons does not exist, findChat will return nothing)

    if (!$chatid) {
        # the chat does not exist
    }
}

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $friend = checkInput($_POST["name"]);
    $_POST = array();
    checkChat($me, $friend);
}
?>
```

Comment: get an array to iterate and found your table? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'yourdb' 
    AND table_name = 'testtable'
LIMIT 1;
```

Alternatively, you can use SHOW TABLES

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'yourtable';
```

If there is a row in the resultset, table exists otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query should be handled via any mysqli_fetch_XXXXX function

```
$sqlresult = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

and then compared

```
if ($sqlresult) {
    echo '<script>alert("It works.");</script>';
}
```